# fetch body of email imap_fetchbody()

Tags: php, imap

How to fetch the body of an email..

With this example only about 25% of all email bodies are fetched!?

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->stream, $header->msgno);

if(!empty($structure->parts[1])){
    $message = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $header->msgno, '1');

    switch($structure->parts[1]->encoding){
        case 1:
            $message = imap_8bit($message);
            break;

        case 3:
            $message = imap_base64($message);
            break;

        case 4:
            $message = imap_qprint($message);
            break;
    }

    echo $message;
}
```

## update

```
// gets 35 of 131
$message = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $header->msgno, '1');

// gets 10 of 131
$message = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $header->msgno, '1.2');
```

Comment: "25% of all email bodies"? You get all the messages, but only 1/4 of each message? or of 16 messages, you only get 4?

Comment: try it just with $message = imap_fetchbody($mailbox,$email, 1.2); get rid of the other stuff for testing

Comment: change '1.1' to '1.2' and give it a try

Comment: You need to look at the structure, and find the text/html or text/plain part.  If it has both parts, the top level ('1') part will be multipart/alternative.  If it additionally has attachment, the top level will likely be multipart/related, with a multipart/alternative subpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :D

```
public function parse_mail($header){
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->stream, $header->msgno);

    if(isset($structure->parts)){
        $parse = $this->parse_parts($structure->parts, $header->msgno);
    }
    else{
        $parse = $this->parse_parts($structure, $header->msgno);
    }

    if($parse){
        print_r($parse);
    }
}

private function parse_parts($parts, $msgno){
    $message = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $msgno, '1');

    if(!empty($parts->encoding)){
        switch($parts->encoding){
            /*case 1:
                $message = imap_8bit($message);
                break;*/

            case 3:
                $message = imap_base64($message);
                break;

            case 4:
                $message = imap_qprint($message);
                break;
        }
    }

    return $message;
}
```